# Is there such a thing as "DTIME($n^k$)-completeness"?

Tags: computational-complexity

That is, is there a conception of a problem's being $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^k)$-complete for some fixed value of $k$?  For example, it seems like it should be provable--likely via a Turing-machine construction--that searching an unsorted list would be $\mathrm{DTIME}(n)$-complete; or that finding a subsequence optimizing some catamorphic objective function would be $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^2)$-complete.  Not sure about $n^3$ or higher.  Do such proofs exist?

---

**1 Jan 2020:** In view of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3493887/543533), I realize I did a disservice by failing to point out that my question is conditioned on resource limitations for the reductions being allowed.  It makes sense to want a $o(n^k)$-time reduction for a $O(n^k)$-time problem.  This being impossible for $k=1$, that particular case might need a reduction technique I haven't even considered.

---

**17 Jan 2020**

### Constant-time mapping reduction for $\mathrm{DTIME}(n)$

Here is a sketch of how a proof of what I'm speculatively calling '$\mathrm{DTIME}(n)$-completeness' might go down.  The reduction is to the [(right) fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) from functional programming.

Suppose we start with a Turing machine $T_L$ that recognizes a language $L$ in $O(n)$ time.  If it always completes in under $c \cdot n$ steps, for constant $c$, then $T_L$ is equivalent to a primitive recursive function making no more than $c$ passes over the input.  By the *universal* and *fusion* properties [1], all $c$ passes may be combined into one and factored out.  In a Haskell-ish notation,

$$ \exists f, z. \ T_M \cong fold\, f\, z $$

Let the $fold$ function be implemented by a machine $T_{fold}$ which takes three inputs: a description of another Turing machine $T_f$ implementing the functionality of $f$, which it then simulates; the input to $f$; and a seed value $z$ for the catamorphism.  $T_f$ and $z$ only need to be constructed once, the cost of which depends only on $T_L$ itself.  Since the mean runtime of $T_f$ must be $O(1)$, its simulation by $T_{fold}$, even on a single-tape machine, remains $O(1)$, and the runtime of the compound machine $(T_{fold}\  T_f\  z)$ stays at $O(n)$.  Consequently, by passing instances of $L$ to $(T_{fold}\ T_f\ z)$ I can postulate
$$\forall L \in  \mathrm{DTIME}(n).\ L \le_m fold$$
  With the reduction's overhead depending on $L$ but not on the size of the input, it is $O(1)$.

I can roughly envision an inductive argument, using this as the base case, extending to a $k$-fold $fold$ composition and $\mathrm{DTIME}(n^k)$, but I don't have the details.  Due to this lack of completeness as well as rigor (what if the $O(n)$ complexity of $T_L$ was amortized?), I am unwilling yet to posit this as an answer to my own question.  I also can't shake the feeling that a ready resolution to it all may be available from a [fp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) expert, now that it is turning in that direction.

[1]: Hutton, G. (1999). [*A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold*](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf). Journal of Functional Programming, 9(4), 355–372. doi: 10.1017/s0956796899003500

Comment: Under which reductions?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker: In the same way that Cook and Levin had to establish SAT as being NP-complete before Karp reductions could begin, I think that an initial proof of the hypothesized $\mathrm{DTIME}(n)$-completeness and its ilk would need to use "lower-level" proof techniques.  (On deterministic machines, in contrast to Cook-Levin.)  Whether this is possible and/or accomplished is the thrust of my question, so if I could answer yours, I would have an answer to mine!

Answer (score 1):

[Cook-Levin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem) theorem result is, and I quote:

> That is, any problem in NP can be reduced in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine to the problem of determining whether a Boolean formula is satisfiable.

It is redundant to define polynomial (or even [Log-space reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-space_reduction) reductions between $DTIME(n^{k_1})\text{ and }DTIME(n^{k_2})$

For polynomial reduction, the reduction itself can solve the problem.
Which means every $L_1\in DTIME(n^{k_1})\leq_p DTIME(n)$ under reduction $p$ thats solves $L_1$ the solution as output.

For Log-space reduction, The reduction can square the size of the input for example by repeating each letter in the input $n$ times.
This means $$\forall L_1\in DTIME(n^{2k})\ \ \exists L_2\in DTIME(n^{k}) \ \ s.t\ \ L_1\leq_p L_2 $$

**Important Remark**
This does not mean $DTIME(n^{k + 1}) = DTIME(n^{k})$ as the [Time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) proves

Maybe you will be interested in the [$P$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete) class (under log-space reductions).

Comment: You're right; I am interested in your $P$-completeness suggestion, which would have made for a better comparison than Cook-Levin.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your earlier comment--if you are saying that polynomial-time reductions trivialize my question, that is certainly true.  If your answer is that polynomial-time and log-space reductions are the only resource prescriptions in use, and therefore the complexity classes that are the topic of my post are *not* generally recognized to exist, then that, as matter of record, may also be true.

Comment: Also, it was the time hierarchy theorem which got me thinking about partitioning $\mathrm{DTIME}$ this way in the first place.

Comment: @Dumaiu Don't be sorry! I was struggling with this question regarding the Log space class hierarchy! My earlier comment was meant to make you think about the definitions.

Comment: @Dumaiu please [accept the answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3286/641481) if it was useful :)

Comment: Don't worry, I've not forgotten.  I just haven't had much time to work on this recently.

Comment: I appreciate your prodding me on this; something eventually popped into place.  Please see the section I've added to my post, about why a $DTIME(n)$-complete problem may not be as silly as it first sounds.

Comment: @Dumaiu I did not say it was silly! My first question was "under which reduction", to which you answer in the update: **constant reduction**. I think it is very interesting speaking on the lower bound of problems, which is also a direction you might find interesting :)

Comment: I'm glad you think so.  No, you didn't call it 'silly', you more polite than that; but, from my OP, you would have been excused for viewing it as silly.  The reduction complexity is the interesting part!  And even I didn't know just what I was talking about at first.  That is the risk of asking for help: if I wait until I perfectly understand my topic, I will never ask anything...